# Categorical linear-model coefficients from a pairwise competition experiment

Tags: r, categorical-data, inference, linear-model

I am presenting a question for which there may be a simple statistical answer, but I have prefaced it with perhaps a longer explanation, to err on the side of caution, in hopes that the data make more sense. I hope you find it interesting also.

### Background

I have results from a microbiological experiment, involving pairwise mixtures of five types of bacteria. Each bacterial type (called a *genotype*) is labelled alphabetically {A,B,C,D,E}. Thus the pairings look something like (A vs. A, A vs. B, A vs. C, ... ,E vs. E). For brevity I denote these competitions as ordered pairs (A,A), (A,B) and so on.

Each of the pairs bacteria are grown together in a test tube with limited resources.  From the data I collect about their growth I can see how well each genotype competes with all others, and importantly, determine which of the two was the better competitor, for each pair. The resultant values are a measure of a kind of relative fitness in competition, termed the "selection coefficient". Briefly, an ordered pair of two competing bacteria (A,B), $s>0$ when A is a better competitor than B, $s<0$ when the converse is true, and $s\approx0$ when I don't notice a measurable difference between the two.

*(I won't mention more about how I measured the selection coefficients, since it's a different story altogether. But for clarify, it is measured from the log change of frequencies of the two types of bacteria in the test tube. If the frequencies of the two competing bacteria, A and B, are denoted by frequencies $a$ and $b$, and $b=1-a$, then the selection coefficient for the competition (A,B)is given as $$s_{(A,B)}=\frac{d}{dt} \ln{\frac{a}{1-a}}$$ .)*

There is an extra level of detail to these experiments: each bacteria is labelled with a fluorescent label, so I can distinguish between each genotype when grown in pairs. To be thorough, I have labelled each of the five genotypes using three colors: Green, Cyan, and Orange. Importantly, the fluorescent label may also burdens the cell's growth, though that depends on the color: Cyan and Orange don't seem to affect the growth of the bacteria, but the green label seems to slow the bacteria down.

This means the competition of two bacteria of genotype A can be done in three different ways: A(cyan) vs. A(green), A(orange) vs. A(green), A(cyan) vs. A(orange). The resulting measurement from a competition like (A(cyan),A(green)) will yield a selection coefficient $s>0$ if indeed Cyan is less burdensome for the bacteria than Green.

Taking these two facts together, the overall selection coefficient can be represented as a sum of two selection coefficients, one representing the effect of the genotype, and one representing the effect of the colors. Thus,

$$ s_{A(cyan),B(green)} = s_{A,B} + s_{cyan,green}.$$

### Setup

The data corresponds to seventy five different competitions, which can be visualized as three square tables. As an example, here is the table of all pairwise competitions for the Cyan vs. Green competitions

$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
    (A_{cyan},A_{green}) & (A_{cyan},B_{green})  & \cdots & (A_{cyan},E_{green}) \\
    (B_{cyan},A_{green}) & (B_{cyan},B_{green}) & \cdots & (B_{cyan},E_{green})\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    (E_{cyan},A_{green}) & (E_{cyan},B_{green}) & \cdots & (E_{cyan},E_{green})\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

There are two more tables like these for the other two color combinations. I have done each of these 75 competitions four times (replicate experiments).

Here is a `data.frame` of simulated selection coefficients to help demonstrate the problem. Note that the pair of flourescent probes used is denoted by the first letter of each color, thus Cyan vs. Green is "CvO" under the column `pair`. Then, each of the two genotypes is displayed as a separate column, resulting in two columns `gen1` and `gen2`. Replicates are denoted under the column `rep`.

```
library(tidyverse)
##To make simulated dateset
##Cyan and orange don't burden growth, and green burden assigned as color_effect
##Genotypes D and E are significantly worse competitors
st.dev = 0.03; color_effect = 0.05; weak_gen = -0.05;
set.seed(1)
simul_fitdat <- 
  expand.grid(color_pair=c("CvO","CvG","OvG"),
              gen1=LETTERS[1:5],gen2=LETTERS[1:5],rep=1:4) %>% 
  #Adding color effect
  mutate(s=case_when(
    color_pair == "CvG" ~ rnorm(n(),mean=color_effect,sd=st.dev),
    color_pair == "OvG" ~ rnorm(n(),mean=color_effect,sd=st.dev),
    color_pair == "CvO" ~rnorm(n(),mean=0,sd=st.dev))) %>% 
  ## adding weak_gen effect to genA and genB
  mutate(s=case_when(
    gen1 %in% c("D","E") ~ s+rnorm(n(),mean=weak_gen,sd=st.dev),
    gen2 %in% c("D","E") ~ s+rnorm(n(),mean=-weak_gen,sd=st.dev),
    T~s))

simul_lm <- lm(s ~ color_pair + gen1 + gen2, data=simul_fitdat)
summary(simul_lm)
```

Here is the output summary I get:

```
Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    0.0063047  0.0079558   0.792   0.4287    
color_pairCvG  0.0606199  0.0058757  10.317  < 2e-16 ***
color_pairOvG  0.0571443  0.0058757   9.726  < 2e-16 ***
gen1B          0.0002638  0.0075855   0.035   0.9723    
gen1C         -0.0158681  0.0075855  -2.092   0.0373 *  
gen1D         -0.0741245  0.0075855  -9.772  < 2e-16 ***
gen1E         -0.0815653  0.0075855 -10.753  < 2e-16 ***
gen2B          0.0013081  0.0075855   0.172   0.8632    
gen2C          0.0026712  0.0075855   0.352   0.7250    
gen2D          0.0326918  0.0075855   4.310 2.24e-05 ***
gen2E          0.0224745  0.0075855   2.963   0.0033 ** 
---
```

As expected, the color effects for green are well estimated by the model. The competitive deficits of genotypes D and E were not as well estimated. Note that genotypes D and E have positive coefficients in gen2 because selection coefficient preserves the order, and so the coefficient describes the fitness of a genotype when competed against D or E. So really it should be that coefficients $gen2D = -gen1D$: the two model coefficients for D are "mirrored" (based on whether it was in the numerator or denominator of the selection coefficient calculation).

### Questions

(I don't expect all of these questions answered but hopefully if one of these is obvious for you to explain you can feel free to just respond to that one).

1. I ran the code multiple times with different seeds and the competitive deficit of genotypes D and E are routinely overestimated when they are in gen1, and underestimated when they are in gen2. Is it a stupid mistake in my code? probably. But changing the seed and also increasing number of replicates don't seem to change this result.
2. Ideally, I would pool all of the data about genotypes D and E as a single effect, but I can't think of how to do this. I know that the data layout is not a unique solution: for example, you can place the two colors as separate columns instead of as a single one. (I have a feeling that taking the average of the two linear model coefficients for genotype D, (i.e. $genD = (gen1D - gen2D)/2$), even though it operationally works, would be committing a statistical felony. Not sure how the uncertainty would carry forward in that case either).
3. Is this one of the cases when it is OK to run a model without an intercept? That way at least I can de-confound the effect of CvO from gen1A.
4. I have a suspicion that in my actual data, the selection coefficient is not a simple sum of the color and genotype effects: there is actually an interaction of the genotype with the color. So something like $s_{A(cyan),B(green)} = s_{A,B} + s_{cyan,green} + \epsilon_{A+cyan} - \epsilon_{B+green}$. If I don't know which genotype interacts with which color, I assume I have to create my linear model with the two interaction terms lm(s~ color_pair + gen1 + gen2 + color_pair*gen1 + color_pair*gen2)?

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your experiments are very interesting! Thank you for explaining how they are set up. My answer is long but it addresses all four questions. Along the way we learn about design matrices and contrasts.

Let's start with question #1. I'm afraid there is a mistake in your code: In the second *mutate* statement, you increase the selection coefficient *s* by *weak_gen* if genotype *gen1* is D or E and decrease it by *weak_gen* if genotype *gen2* is D or E. What happens if the pairing is (D,D), (D,E), (E,D) or (E,E)? You still increase *s* by *weak_gen* even though the two effects actually cancel.

The following code snippet fixes this mistake. I add random noise only after generating the selection coefficient as the sum of the color effect and the genotype effect. You add more noise to the competitions of D and E (inadvertently?)

```r
sim_dat <- sim_dat %>%
  mutate(
    # Add color effect
    s = case_when(
      color_pair == "CvG" ~ color_effect,
      color_pair == "OvG" ~ color_effect,
      TRUE ~ 0
    ),
    # Add weak_gen effect to competitions of D, E against A, B, C
    s = s + case_when(
      gen1 %in% c("D", "E") & gen2 %in% c("A", "B", "C") ~ weak_gen,
      gen2 %in% c("D", "E") & gen1 %in% c("A", "B", "C") ~ -weak_gen,
      TRUE ~ 0
    ),
    # Add random error
    s = s + rnorm(n(), sd = st.dev)
  )
```

*Note*: I attach my simulation code at the end. It allows to specify different effects for each color and each genotype and, optionally, interactions between colors and genotypes.

*Design matrix*

Onto question #2. We can estimate a single effect for each genotype by creating dummy variables for each genotype. Same for colors. These dummy variables are unusual because they take three values {-1, 0, 1} to describe participation in a two-way competition.

Let's demonstrate the idea by transforming the data frame.

```r
sim_dat <- sim_dat %>%
  mutate(
    cyan = str_starts(color_pair, "C") - str_ends(color_pair, "C"),
    green = str_starts(color_pair, "G") - str_ends(color_pair, "G"),
    orange = str_starts(color_pair, "O") - str_ends(color_pair, "O"),
    A = (gen1 == "A") - (gen2 == "A"),
    B = (gen1 == "B") - (gen2 == "B"),
    C = (gen1 == "C") - (gen2 == "C"),
    D = (gen1 == "D") - (gen2 == "D"),
    E = (gen1 == "E") - (gen2 == "E")
  )
head(sim_dat)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 13
#>   color_pair gen1  gen2    rep        s  cyan green orange     A     #> B     C     D     E
#>   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <int>    <dbl> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 CvO        A     A         1 -0.0188      1     0     -1     0     0     0     0     0
#> 2 CvO        A     A         2  0.00551     1     0     -1     0     0     0     0     0
#> 3 CvO        A     A         3 -0.0251      1     0     -1     0     0     0     0     0
#> 4 CvO        A     A         4  0.0479      1     0     -1     0     0     0     0     0
#> 5 CvO        A     B         1  0.00989     1     0     -1     1    -1     0     0     0
#> 6 CvO        A     B         2 -0.0246      1     0     -1     1    -1     0     0     0
```

The color columns (cyan, green, orange) and the genotype columns (A, B, C, D, E) describe each competition:

- 0s indicate that a color/genotype didn't participate in the competition.
- 1s and -1s indicate the left/right order in the color and genotype pairs.

With this coding (cyan, green, orange) = (1, 0, -1) is equivalent to color_pair = CvO; (A, B, C, D, E) = (1, -1, 0, 0, 0) is equivalent to gen1 = A, gen2 = B; (A, B, C, D, E) = (-1, 1, 0, 0, 0) is equivalent to gen1 = B, gen2 = A. To preserve the oder we use 1 for the left competitor and -1 for the right competitor.

Competitions between two bacteria of the same genotype are coded as (A, B, C, D, E) = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0). While we retain (implicitly) the information that a genotype competes against itself, we lose the information which genotype. Nevertheless, if there are no interactions between colors and genotypes, the design matrix we've constructed is correct. (We can extend the design matrix to include interactions; see the update below.)

Now let's fit a regression with color and genotype main effects and *no intercept*. We don't need an intercept as question #3 points out.

```r
sim_fit <- lm(s ~ 0 + cyan + green + orange + E + D + C + B + A, data = sim_dat)

broom::tidy(sim_fit)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   term   estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 cyan    0.00150   0.00236     0.636  5.25e- 1
#> 2 green  -0.0491    0.00236   -20.8    1.01e-59
#> 3 orange NA        NA          NA     NA       
#> 4 E      -0.0515    0.00373   -13.8    1.03e-33
#> 5 D      -0.0487    0.00373   -13.0    5.28e-31
#> 6 C      -0.00437   0.00373    -1.17   2.43e- 1
#> 7 B      -0.00548   0.00373    -1.47   1.44e- 1
#> 8 A      NA        NA          NA     NA
```

The dummy-variable formulation sounded like a good idea but two effects — one color and one genotype — are not estimated. Why?

The design matrix X, which we constructed explicitly, contains two linear dependencies. If we know the value for *cyan* and *green*, we can work out the value for *orange*. Same with the genotypes: If we know the value of B, C, D and E, we can deduce the value for A. More generally, if we know k-1 values, then we know the k-th also because the values sum up to 0 by design.

*Contrasts*

The statistical term for a linear combination is a *contrast*. With a contrast, we can estimate comparisons (differences between effects and linear combinations of effects), not absolute effects. Usually, one level (ie, one color / one genotype) is chosen as the reference, so that we can interpret estimated coefficients as differences from the reference. In this case, since the design matrix is constructed explicitly, the reference level is rather obvious in the summary table: it's *orange* for colors and A for genotypes.

It's important to keep in mind that the terms in the table above are *contrasts*: the 1st and 2nd row are the color contrasts *cyan - orange* and *green - orange*, the 4th to 7th row are the genotype contrasts E - A, D - A, C - A and B - A. For each contrast we have its estimate and standard error. For example, E is *less fit* than A by 0.0515 with *se*=0.00373.

We notice a couple of interesting things: a) both color contrasts have std. error 0.00236 and all genotype contrasts have std. error 0.00373; b) the genotype contrasts have higher error than the color contrasts. This is explained by the balanced design: each genotype participates in the same number of competitions as any other genotype; same for colors. A color participates in more competitions than a genotype, so the color effects are estimated with smaller error.

So now we understand design matrices and contrasts but so far we only know the contrasts between A and the other four genotypes. What if we want to compare E to A, B, C and D? An easy way to do it to make predictions for the contrasts (aka competitions) we are interested in.

Let's compare A to B, C, D, E. We already have these pairwise contrasts, so this is a check that we can reproduce the numbers in the summary table. *Note*: There are no color-genotype interactions in this model so I don't specify colors.

```r
contrasts <- tribble(
  ~cyan,~green,~orange,~A,~B,~C,~D,~E,
  0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,
  0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1
)

broom::augment(newdata = contrasts, se_fit = TRUE, interval = "confidence")
#> Warning in predict.lm(x, newdata = newdata, na.action = na.pass, se.fit
#> = .se_fit, : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
#> # A tibble: 4 × 12
#>    cyan green orange     A     B     C     D     E .fitted   .lower .upper   .se.fit
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     0     0      0     1    -1     0     0     0 0.00548 -0.00187 0.0128   0.00373
#> 2     0     0      0     1     0    -1     0     0 0.00437 -0.00298 0.0117   0.00373
#> 3     0     0      0     1     0     0    -1     0 0.0487   0.0414  0.0561   0.00373
#> 4     0     0      0     1     0     0     0    -1 0.0515   0.0442  0.0588   0.00373
```

Yes! Same estimates and standard errors. The sign is flipped because now we compare A to *other* while in the summary we compare *other* to A. Let's repeat to compare E to A, B, C, D.

```r
contrasts <- tribble(
  ~cyan,~green,~orange,~A,~B,~C,~D,~E,
  0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,
  0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1
)

broom::augment(sim_fit, newdata = contrasts, se_fit = TRUE, interval = "confidence")
#> Warning in predict.lm(x, newdata = newdata, na.action = na.pass, se.fit
#> = .se_fit, : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
#> # A tibble: 4 × 12
#>    cyan green orange     A     B     C     D     E  .fitted  .lower   .upper   .se.fit
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     0     0      0    -1     0     0     0     1 -0.0515  -0.0588 -0.0442    0.00373
#> 2     0     0      0     0    -1     0     0     1 -0.0460  -0.0534 -0.0387    0.00373
#> 3     0     0      0     0     0    -1     0     1 -0.0471  -0.0545 -0.0398    0.00373
#> 4     0     0      0     0     0     0    -1     1 -0.00278 -0.0101  0.00456   0.00373
```

And there you have it — a straightforward method to compute pairwise contrasts with standard errors and 95% confidence intervals.

*Interactions*

We can extend this process to include interactions. The trick is to add a dummy variable for each color-genotype combination we want to test. As with the main effects the value is 1 if the color-genotype combination is "the left competitor", -1 if it's "the right competitor" and 0 otherwise.

For example, here is how to create dummy variables for the interactions between each genotype and the color *green*.

```r
sim_dat <- sim_dat %>%
  mutate(
    GxA = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "A") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "A"),
    GxB = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "B") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "B"),
    GxC = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "C") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "C"),
    GxD = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "D") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "D"),
    GxE = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "E") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "E")
  )
```

Then we simply include the interactions in the model formula. *Note*: I show how to simulate data with interaction(s) below. I've added just one interaction, between *green* and *A*; it reduces A's selection coefficient by 0.01. There is one more linear dependence but otherwise the interactions are well estimated.

```r
sim_fit <- lm(
  s ~ 0 + cyan + green + orange + E + D + C + B + A + GxA + GxB + GxC + GxD + GxE,
  data = sim_dat
)

broom::tidy(sim_fit) %>% print(n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 13 × 5
#>    term    estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>    <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 cyan    0.000362  0.000859     0.422  6.74e- 1
#>  2 green  -0.0504    0.00201    -25.0    1.85e-74
#>  3 orange NA        NA           NA     NA       
#>  4 E      -0.0495    0.00166    -29.8    4.07e-90
#>  5 D      -0.0300    0.00166    -18.0    2.97e-49
#>  6 C       0.0282    0.00166     17.0    2.87e-45
#>  7 B       0.00934   0.00166      5.62   4.53e- 8
#>  8 A      NA        NA           NA     NA       
#>  9 GxA    -0.0106    0.00288     -3.67   2.93e- 4
#> 10 GxB     0.000715  0.00288      0.248  8.04e- 1
#> 11 GxC     0.00417   0.00288      1.45   1.49e- 1
#> 12 GxD     0.000775  0.00288      0.269  7.88e- 1
#> 13 GxE    NA        NA           NA     NA
```

---

Alternative data simulation. Allows for specifying individual color and genotype effects as well as color-genotype interactions.

```r
library("tidyverse")

st.dev <- 0.03

color_effects <- tribble(
  ~color, ~s,
  "C", 0,
  "O", 0,
  "G", -0.05
)

genotype_effects <- tribble(
  ~genotype, ~s,
  "A", 0,
  "B", 0.01,
  "C", 0.03,
  "D", -0.03,
  "E", -0.05
)
interactions <- tribble(
  ~color, ~genotype, ~s,
  "G", "A", -0.01
)

sim_dat <-
  expand_grid(
    color_pair = c("CvO", "CvG", "OvG"),
    gen1 = LETTERS[1:5],
    gen2 = LETTERS[1:5],
    rep = 1:4
  ) %>%
  separate(
    color_pair, c("col1", "col2"),
    sep = "v", remove = FALSE
  ) %>%
  # Specify color main effects
  inner_join(
    color_effects %>% rename(s_col1 = s),
    by = c("col1" = "color")
  ) %>%
  inner_join(
    color_effects %>% rename(s_col2 = s),
    by = c("col2" = "color")
  ) %>%
  # Specify genotype main effects
  inner_join(
    genotype_effects %>% rename(s_gen1 = s),
    by = c("gen1" = "genotype")
  ) %>%
  inner_join(
    genotype_effects %>% rename(s_gen2 = s),
    by = c("gen2" = "genotype")
  ) %>%
  # Specify color-genotype interactions
  left_join(
    interactions %>% rename(s_col1xgen1 = s),
    by = c("col1" = "color", "gen1" = "genotype")
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    interactions %>% rename(s_col2xgen2 = s),
    by = c("col2" = "color", "gen2" = "genotype")
  ) %>%
  replace_na(
    list(s_col1xgen1 = 0, s_col2xgen2 = 0)
  ) %>%
  # Add up all the effects (main & interactions)
  mutate(
    s = (s_col1 - s_col2) + (s_gen1 - s_gen2) + (s_col1xgen1 - s_col2xgen2),
    s = s + rnorm(n(), sd = st.dev)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    cyan = str_starts(color_pair, "C") - str_ends(color_pair, "C"),
    green = str_starts(color_pair, "G") - str_ends(color_pair, "G"),
    orange = str_starts(color_pair, "O") - str_ends(color_pair, "O"),

    A = (gen1 == "A") - (gen2 == "A"),
    B = (gen1 == "B") - (gen2 == "B"),
    C = (gen1 == "C") - (gen2 == "C"),
    D = (gen1 == "D") - (gen2 == "D"),
    E = (gen1 == "E") - (gen2 == "E"),

    GxA = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "A") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "A"),
    GxB = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "B") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "B"),
    GxC = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "C") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "C"),
    GxD = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "D") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "D"),
    GxE = (col1 == "G" & gen1 == "E") - (col2 == "G" & gen2 == "E")
  )

sim_fit <- lm(s ~ 0 + cyan + green + orange + E + D + C + B + A, data = sim_dat)

broom::tidy(sim_fit)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   term   estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 cyan    0.00157   0.00248     0.635  5.26e- 1
#> 2 green  -0.0507    0.00248   -20.5    1.78e-58
#> 3 orange NA        NA          NA     NA       
#> 4 E      -0.0491    0.00391   -12.6    3.14e-29
#> 5 D      -0.0289    0.00391    -7.38   1.64e-12
#> 6 C       0.0300    0.00391     7.66   2.77e-13
#> 7 B       0.00735   0.00391     1.88   6.14e- 2
#> 8 A      NA        NA          NA     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Very neat! Before your answer, I managed to get decent results using `emmeans`, but this seems to return just what I'm looking for right in the `lm` summary table. One Q: I am actually interested in retaining information about self-competition because of what I mentioned in the original post (Q#4): e.g. A_cyan vs A_green will ≠ 0 if genotype A particularly dislikes cyan. I'm not sure how to circumvent this using integer indices like you used for the grouping columns, but it seems to work if I made a column "whichself" = "X" if the competition is X vs X, and "Nonself" otherwise. Is that OK?

Comment: The idea for a "whichself" column is a good one but doesn't quite work. Instead you can add color-genotype interactions explicitly. I've updated my answer to show how. I think this is all four questions answered (hopefully correctly)!

Comment: Thanks, works beautifully. One thing I did like about `emmeans` is that it computes the contrast and also provides a standard error for the contrast. Thus A is fitter than C by ___ ± ___. Any idea how to compute such a standard error of contrast? I found `se.contrast' which works on `aov` but not `lm`. Is `aov` an appropriate tool for this analysis as well?

Comment: *emmeans* is cool but it doesn't work here because it doesn't understand this "unusual" design matrix. The coefficients in the table are contrasts. The reference level is the color/genotype with the NAs. Take color = C with estimate = -0.00437 and std. error 0.00373. This is an estimate for the contrast C - A: -0.00437 ± 2*0.00373.

Comment: This turned out to be one epic answer. Now you should make sure you understand it and if you have followup questions it would be better to create a new post.